# Testing accuracy 0.5 TensorFlow RNN variable length strings

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

After having adapted the following code that you find in the link at the end of the post, that is, reading from the variable length strings file with alphabet 0-1 and ability to set the number of layers through `LSTMCell` and `MultiRNNCell` I get a value of accuracy 0.5.

In particular, strings are a regular language, and each string is labeled as accepting and not accepting.

I wanted some advice on what parameters vary to obtain a value of greater accuracy:

Possible parameters to be set:

> learning_rate - training_iters - batch_size - display_step - n_layers
>   - seq_max_len - n_hidden - n_classes.

Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/dynamic_rnn.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer this question without more information. I will address each parameter independently from a general point of view:

- n_classes: from your description I understand that you are solving a binary classification problem. Therefore, n_classes=2.
- seq_max_len denotes the maximal length of the sequence. You can start with computing the max length of your input and use it (or any other reasonable length if max length is too big).
- n_layers, n_hidden - I suggest to adjust these params while you obtain a model that is capable of learning. To begin with, set them to some low value, e.g. n_layers = 1 or 2, n_hidden = 64.
- batch_size - 100 or something close should be OK to begin with,
- display_step - it does not affect the quality of the resulted model, just how frequent the script prints intermediate stats.
- learning_rate - you should choose this value so that the model loss decreases. If loss does not decrease, select a lower learning_rate
- training_iters - you should monitor the loss (and other metrics) on validation set and select an optimal number of iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am trying in this way since yesterday.

Comment: You are welcome. The first thing to check is whether loss value is decreasing when you train the model. If it's not - it's an indication of problems with a model or optimization (maybe learning rate is too high).

Comment: I tried to change the parameters, but unfortunately I always get low values of accuracy and higher error.